# Unable to deserialize ActorRef to send result to different Actor

Tags: serialization, apache-spark, actor, spark-streaming

I am starting to use Spark Streaming to process a real time data feed I am getting. My scenario is I have a Akka actor receiver using "with ActorHelper", then I have my Spark job doing some mappings and transformation and then I want to send the result to another actor.

My issue is the last part. When trying to send to another actor Spark is raising an exception:

> 15/02/20 16:43:16 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to deserialize a serialized ActorRef without an ActorSystem in scope. Use 'akka.serialization.Serialization.currentSystem.withValue(system) { ... }'

The way I am creating this last actor is the following:

```
val actorSystem = SparkEnv.get.actorSystem
val lastActor = actorSystem.actorOf(MyLastActor.props(someParam), "MyLastActor")
```

And then using it like this:

```
result.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.foreachPartition(lastActor ! _))
```

I am not sure where or how to do the advise "Use 'akka.serialization.Serialization.currentSystem.withValue(system) { ... }'". Do I need to set anything special through configuration? Or create my actor differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I collect before I send to the actor it works like a charm:

```
result.foreachRDD(rdd =>  rdd.collect().foreach(producer ! _))
```

Comment: Be careful with this solution. Make sure that you have a sufficiently small dataset when using `collect()` (as specified in the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#actions))

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following example to access an actor outside of the Spark domain.

/*
     * Following is the use of actorStream to plug in custom actor as receiver
     *
     * An important point to note:
     * Since Actor may exist outside the spark framework, It is thus user's responsibility
     * to ensure the type safety, i.e type of data received and InputDstream
     * should be same.
     *
     * For example: Both actorStream and SampleActorReceiver are parameterized
     * to same type to ensure type safety.
     */

```
val lines = ssc.actorStream[String](
  Props(new SampleActorReceiver[String]("akka.tcp://test@%s:%s/user/FeederActor".format(
    host, port.toInt))), "SampleReceiver")
```