# How to use an Akka actor from the Spark nodes of a cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, akka

Having a Spark cluster running a certain application, I would like to use an Akka actor to stream data from within each of the Spark nodes in the cluster. That is: the nodes are processing data in some way, and **in parallel** the actor is sending some other data within the node to an external process.

Now, these are the possible options:

1. Just create the ActorRef through a regular ActorSystem: not possible as the ActorSystem instance is not Serializable and it will fail at runtime
2. Use the Spark internal ActorSystem to create the actor: not a good option since Spark 1.4 as `Spark.get.ActorSystem` is [deprecated](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkEnv)

So what is the best way for the Spark nodes to instantiate a given actor if the options above are not valid? is it possible at all?

This question is somewhat related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765150/akka-trying-to-deserialize-a-serialized-actorref-without-an-actorsystem-in-sco) although formulated on a wider scope

Note: I know I could somehow use Spark streaming for this scenario, but at the moment I would like to explore the feasibility of a pure Akka option