# Trying to deserialize a serialized ActorRef without an ActorSystem in scope - Spark/Akka/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, akka

EDIT:  Exception relating to serialising / deserialising Akka Actor remains after forEach is confirmed to be executing.
I'm learning Akka and encountering this serialisation issue, I'm quite new to Akka and finding it quite difficult to figure out how best to approach a solution.

I have a class where the actorSystem and actor is created, that class calls a method in another class, I'd like to use my actor in that other class.  So far I've tried:

```
Class a:
-create actor
-classB.methodX(actor)

Class b:
-methodX(actorRef)
--actorRef! message
```

currently the message from class b does not get sent whereas the class A ones do, this is making me think that I either need to instantiate a new Actor with the ActorRef that I'm passing in or, it's completely wrong.

I understand that the system needs to be present on all nodes but I'm unsure how to do that.

Edit: Code Snippets:

```
ClassA:
  private val system = ActorSystem("System")
  private val metricActor= system.actorOf(Props(new MetricActor("metrics")), name = "metrics")

metricActor ! message works fine

writeFiles(metricActor) //writeFiles is in another class


writeFiles(actor: ActorRef) {
  f.forEach(v => {
  actor ! message // this doesn't seem to work
})
}
```

Edited to provide more code.

full example of classB as it were

```
def writeFiles(bucket: String, filesToWrite: RDD[(String, String)], actor:ActorRef): Unit =
filesToWrite.foreachPartition(f => {
  f.foreach(v => {
    try {
      //actor  ! ProcessSingleItem(MetricItem("File Created"))
      logger.debug(s"Writing file:")
      writeFile()
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        //actor ! ProcessSingleItem(CloudWatchMetricItem("File create failure")) 
        logger.error("Error creating file", e)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Akka actors are just small parts of a bigger machinery that is hidden away. The actor system is more like the car's engine and your actors can be said to be like accelerator etc. Do you think the accelerator alone is going to get you moving if the whole car is missing?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh What might you suggest for solving my current dilemma?  Should every node have a car? That seems extreme.  Should a node have the capability of sending a message to the foot telling ti to press the accelerator?

Comment: The short answer -> Whatever node needs to behave like a car needs to have capabilities of a car. Just design your solution so that only car type nodes need to behave like cars. Other nodes can stay lightweight.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh - Thanks for taking the time to comment, it doesn't really help though.

Comment: Yes. I certainly know it won't help much. Its just that actor can not function without an actor system. So you will just have to design with that in mind.

Comment: Is this resolved? If you are expecting answers on "remoting on Spak" issue, you're much better off asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing should work. You didn't paste the full (but minimal!) code sample so I can't say what's the problem (maybe something in your foreach logic; we don'e even know what f is), but here's what definitely works. Try building up on that.

```
object Test extends App {

  class MetricActor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case a: String => println(a)
    }
  }

  private val system = ActorSystem("System")
  private val metricActor= system.actorOf(Props(new MetricActor()), name = "metrics")

  OtherClass.writeFiles(metricActor) // prints "foo"
}

// this is in other file:
object OtherClass {
  def writeFiles(actor: ActorRef) {
    actor ! "foo"
  }
}
```

EDIT: Turns out after discussion in comments that the problematic part was unrelated to Akka (try block was not even executing), but I will leave this here in case it helps someone.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to answer, I've managed to get an example (like what you wrote) working fine.  I've added some more to the snippet as I think your right with respect to the foreach,  Would you mind taking a look?  Many thanks.

Comment: Hm, I don't see it. Anyways, please provide a full but minimal sample that still causes you problems (that is, strip off any business logic etc. but leave the types, methods, classes, anything needed in order to reproduce the error). By full I mean that it can be instantly copied to a REPL/IDE and ran without missing dependencies etc. Even if I can't help you, this will increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Thanks slouc, should be there now, I was removing the fluff from it.  The calling class creates the system, an actor and then the actor is passed in as the actorRef param

Comment: OK now I see it, but please provide the rest of the code. What does `MetricActor` look like? The problem is definitely not in not having the actor system in the other class, as you can see from my example. Are you sure that the code in the try block even executes? Perhaps filesToWrite is empty or something.

Comment: Hate to be a smartass, but in the future providing a [MCV](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example will help you get quality answers and may even help you to find the bug yourself. If you had stripped down the `writeFiles` method into something more simple (like I did in my example) you would have seen that the akka part is working just fine. ;)

Comment: if you can pull off being a smartass then that's your right :)  It doesn't help that it's foreign code, foreign stack and foreign tech to me but yes, I should've stepped through entire code in debug first.

Comment: Yeah, never mind that it's all foreign to you, you should always strive to provide a stripped-down version when posting here, otherwise people will not bother. You've been here for quite some time now, I'm sure you've witnessed it yourself. If people see `writeFiles // bunch of code here` then they won't bother since it may turn out to be a waste of their time (in case the bug is somewhere inside). Personally, if I see a problem on SO that I can instantly c/p as is, run it and see the same error message as said in the question, then I will surely invest time into trying to figure it out.

Comment: BTW I didn't mean it as a rebuke, more as a friendly advice for future posts that will help you get better feedback :) so, you on the right track now?

Comment: Any advice is good advice especially when it helps get questions answered :)  I think I'm on the right track, currently running a stripped version, function is being executed now but it's still misbeahving

Comment: back on track so to speak, block is executing with exception:  Trying to deserialize a serialized ActorRef without an ActorSystem in scope. Use 'akka.serialization.Serialization.currentSystem.withValue(system) { ... }'

Comment: I can tell you're working with Spark from your `writeFiles` method, right? In that case see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765150/akka-trying-to-deserialize-a-serialized-actorref-without-an-actorsystem-in-sco)

Comment: The link, I've read it several times :)  I can't find an example of how to serialise it and then pass it in, much like the guy's comment on the thread.   The remote doesn't look like an option for me and I've not enough know how to implement the other somethign to work from.

Comment: Sorry, haven't used akka with spark, someone else will have to take it from here. At least we've made some progress from the initial problem :)