# Spark/Akka integration

Tags: scala, apache-spark, akka

I am writing a sample code to integrate Spark/Akka. I am creating an Akka actor within Spark and I am facing the below error.

Code

```
object program {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("SparkTest")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val system = ActorSystem("IntervalBuilder")
    val IBActor = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[IntervalBuilderFSM]), "IB")

    val no = Array("AB", "BC", "CPS")
    val input = sc.parallelize(no)

    for (x <- input) {
      println("=== " + x)
      IBActor ! x
    }
  }
}
```

Error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to deserialize a serialized ActorRef without an ActorSystem in scope. Use 'akka.serialization.Serialization.currentSystem.withValue(system) { ... }'

Comment: For loop closure is executed in different context than the actor system exists. While it could work by accident in local mode, this is not the way to go. You might be able to get something working with Akka cluster with nodes co-located with Spark executors (haven't tried) but I would require way more effort than this. As is, it is just another instance of [(mis)understanding closures](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#understanding-closures-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Akka: "Trying to deserialize a serialized ActorRef without an ActorSystem in scope" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765150/akka-trying-to-deserialize-a-serialized-actorref-without-an-actorsystem-in-sco)